# I don't understand how preg_replace_callback works, how to update from preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace, deprecated, preg-replace-callback

How it will look this using preg_replace_callback?

```
$str = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me', "code2utf('\\1',{$lo})", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you want to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead of using the [`/e` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986331/can-someone-explain-the-e-regex-modifier).

If you want to pass extra parameters to the callback function you could make use of the [`use` indentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier) or wrap the callback in [another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735565/second-parameter-in-preg-replace-callback).

The second example could look like:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/m', function ($matches) use ($lo) {
        // function body with return statement
}, $str
);
```

**Notes**

Your  regex [`\&\#([0-9]+)\;`](https://regex101.com/r/tilDyk/1) will match a string like `&#233333;`. I think you don't have to ecape the `&` and `#`.

In your code you use `return strtoupper($matches[1], $lo);` but [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) takes one parameter instead of 2 parameters.

If this is what you want to  match, then when running [your code](https://3v4l.org/vlG2K) you could see that `$matches[1]` contains `"233333"` so this will be called `return strtoupper("233333");`